# How does a web3py ABI for an ethereum contract with array outputs have to look like?

Tags: javascript, python, web3js, abi, web3py

I have to reverse engineer the ABI of an undocumented function belonging to an ethereum contract.

This is what the raw output split into 256-bit chunks looks like:

```
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060' # unknown
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000220' # unknown
'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e0' # unknown
'000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d' # 13, the array size
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001' # array of quantities
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
'000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d' # 13, the array size
'000000000000000000000000a96760f0efa3a9bc2388915d045acd4da9e23251' # array of addresses
'000000000000000000000000a96760f0efa3a9bc2388915d045acd4da9e23251'
'000000000000000000000000a96760f0efa3a9bc2388915d045acd4da9e23251'
'000000000000000000000000a96760f0efa3a9bc2388915d045acd4da9e23251'
'000000000000000000000000a96760f0efa3a9bc2388915d045acd4da9e23251'
'000000000000000000000000a96760f0efa3a9bc2388915d045acd4da9e23251'
'000000000000000000000000a96760f0efa3a9bc2388915d045acd4da9e23251'
'000000000000000000000000a96760f0efa3a9bc2388915d045acd4da9e23251'
'000000000000000000000000a96760f0efa3a9bc2388915d045acd4da9e23251'
'000000000000000000000000a96760f0efa3a9bc2388915d045acd4da9e23251'
'000000000000000000000000a96760f0efa3a9bc2388915d045acd4da9e23251'
'000000000000000000000000a96760f0efa3a9bc2388915d045acd4da9e23251'
'000000000000000000000000a96760f0efa3a9bc2388915d045acd4da9e23251'
'000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d' # 13, the array size
'0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000405' # array of indices
'0000000000000000000000000000000d00000000000000000000000000000409'
'0000000000000000000000000000000d0000000000000000000000000000040b'
'0000000000000000000000000000001c000000000000000000000000000003a7'
'0000000000000000000000000000001c000000000000000000000000000003a8'
'00000000000000000000000000000064000000000000000000000000000003f2'
'00000000000000000000000000000067000000000000000000000000000003b0'
'00000000000000000000000000000070000000000000000000000000000003c4'
'000000000000000000000000000000850000000000000000000000000000038e'
'0000000000000000000000000000008e000000000000000000000000000003ea'
'0000000000000000000000000000009a000000000000000000000000000003d6'
'0000000000000000000000000000009d000000000000000000000000000003a2'
'0000000000000000000000000000009d000000000000000000000000000003a3'
```

The array size varies. It's 1 for most calls.
This is the ABI I used:

```
abi = {"constant":True,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"dataIndex","type":"uint256"}],
    "name":"getData", "outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"parameter0","type":"uint256"},
                                 {"internalType":"uint256","name":"parameter1","type":"uint256"},
                                 {"internalType":"uint256","name":"parameter2","type":"uint256"},
                                 {"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountArraySize","type":"uint256"},
                                 {"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},
                                 {"internalType":"uint256","name":"addressArraySize","type":"uint256"},
                                 {"internalType":"address","name":"address","type":"address"},
                                 {"internalType":"uint256","name":"indexArraySize","type":"uint256"},
                                 {"internalType":"uint256","name":"index","type":"uint256"}],
    "payable":False, "stateMutability":"view", "type":"function"},
```

This works just fine as long as all array sizes are 1. But when the arrays are larger it will just fill all output fields with values of the first array and discard the rest.

I have looked at ABIs of other contracts and for arrays there is simply `[]` added to the type name.
But changing the outputs to

```
[
    {"internalType":"uint256","name":"parameter0","type":"uint256"},
    {"internalType":"uint256","name":"parameter1","type":"uint256"},
    {"internalType":"uint256","name":"parameter2","type":"uint256"},
    {"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountArraySize","type":"uint256"},
    {"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amount","type":"uint256[]"},        #changed
    {"internalType":"uint256","name":"addressArraySize","type":"uint256"},
    {"internalType":"address[]","name":"address","type":"address[]"},       #changed
    {"internalType":"uint256","name":"indexArraySize","type":"uint256"},
    {"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"index","type":"uint256[]"}          #changed
]
```

only raises `web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not decode contract function call to getData with return data:`

The other ABIs with arrays I looked at have no size fields in the output list, so my guess was that it's implicit.
So I removed those lines:

```
[
    {"internalType":"uint256","name":"parameter0","type":"uint256"},
    {"internalType":"uint256","name":"parameter1","type":"uint256"},
    {"internalType":"uint256","name":"parameter2","type":"uint256"},
    {"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amount","type":"uint256[]"},       
    {"internalType":"address[]","name":"address","type":"address[]"},       
    {"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"index","type":"uint256[]"}
]
```

But it still raises the same error.

What's the correct ABI declaration for output and input arrays?

Answer (score 0):

The first 3 return values are the starting locations of the 3 arrays within the binary return data.
These are also implicit and need not to be declared in the output fields.

Removing the first 3 lines as well fixed the error and web3py now correctly returns the results for arrays that are larger than 1.